# Understanding the concept of data binding in a Spring-MVC app

Tags: java, data-binding, spring-mvc

I'm trying to understand the concept of **data binding** in Spring-MVC with Velocity (I'm learning this framework and porting an app to this platform).

I'm used to getting form variables using `request.getParameter("username")`, in the Spring world it seems that I can perform validation and such against "*form objects*" e.g. a datamodel style object that represent all the fields of a form.

The concept of a validator makes sense, but marshaling the data from a query string to these objects is fuzzy for me still. This is the concept of "Data Binding" correct?

If I'm correct to this point a few specific questions:

- When a "binding" is made between a form variable (say `"username"` for example) and the the field of an object (say `org.a.b.MyNewUserFormObj.username`) is that "binding" a permanent definition such that all subsequent http posts of that form cause the `username` form variable to be assigned to `org.a.b.MyNewUserFormObj.username`?
- How in the world do I accomplish the above binding definition? (if what I've said up to now is correct I feel like Costello in 'Who's on First', I don't even know what I just said!), I just need a conceptual picture.

Thanks for setting straight a brain gone astray.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no magic in data binding.

Actually, Spring simply populate properties of `@ModelAttribute` object with the values of request parameters with the corresponding names (in the simpliest case request parameter have the same name as a property, but [nested properties](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans-conventions) are also supported).

So, if you have

```
<input type = "text" name = "firstName" />
```

and

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    ... getters, setters ...
}
```

you get a value from the form field.

Spring also provides convenient method for creating HTML forms. So, instead of creating form fields manually, you can write in JSP:

```
<form:form modelAttribute = "person" ...>
    <form:input path = "firstName" />
</form:form>
```

or in Velocity (note that in this case `<form>` is created manually and property path is prefixed with the model attribute name):

```
<form ...>
    #springFormInput("person.firstName" "")
</form>
```

Fields of the forms generated this way will be prepopulated with the values of the corresponding properties of the model attribute (that's why model attribute name is needed).

Comment: I'm still a bit fuzzy about who maps the querystring/post data to a Person object. How does spring know that the Person object is the object that should be created from a particular form, and how does it map names from the form data to the setters of the Person object?

Comment: @David: Spring doesn't know anything about mapping of a particular form. When request comes to the controller, Spring looks at the signature of the controller method and maps parameters of the request to the arguments of the method. So, for `@ModelAttribute` argument it creates an object of the specified type and binds request parameters to its properties. Rules of name mapping speicifed in http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans-conventions

Comment: When you say that it "binds request parameters to its properties", referring to, for example, a MyPerson object in the method parameters of the controller, do you mean that for each form variable submitted that it will attempt to call a setter of the MyPerson object. Example, if there is a form parameter called "firstname" and "lastname" that Spring will automagically created a new MyPerson() and then call myPerson.setFirstname(value_from_form) and myPerson.setLastname(value_from_form). Is this what is happening behind the scenes?

Comment: David Parks has a good question. I hope somebody could point or lead us to a Spring document that says whether Spring is using the setters methods to set the properties and if it doesn't use the setters, how could we force Spring to use the getters and setters when accessing the properties of the model object.

Comment: @supertonsky: Spring uses setters in this case, and cannot be configured to access fields directly. Spring documentation doesn't cover this moment well.